# discord.py TypeError: unsupported type annotation <class 'discord.interactions.Interaction'>

Tags: python, discord.py

Original code here:

```
@app_commands.command(name='clearmsg', description="clear the number of messages you want.")
@app_commands.rename(num='quantity')
@app_commands.describe(num='For how many messages you would like to delete (In Arabic numerals).')    
async def clear(self, ctx, num : int, interaction:discord.Interaction):
   await ctx.channel.purge(limit=num)
   await interaction.response.send_message(f"{num} messages were cleared successfully.", embed=EmbedTemplate, ephemeral=True)
```

I was trying to make a slash command let the bot delete certain number of messages

> /clearmsg {quantity} to delete {quantity} message

But the error raised as below:

```
TypeError: unsupported type annotation <class 'discord.interactions.Interaction'>
```

or trying to ignore the interaction argument:

```
@app_commands.command(name='clearmsg', description="clear the number of messages you want.")
@app_commands.rename(num='quantity')
@app_commands.describe(num='For how many messages you would like to delete (In Arabic numerals).')
async def clear(self, ctx, num : int):
  await ctx.channel.purge(limit=num)
  await ctx.respond(f"{num} messages were cleared successfully.", embed=EmbedTemplate, ephemeral=True)
```

another error raised as below:

```
<class 'discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError'>: Command 'clearmsg' raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Interaction' object has no attribute 'respond'
```

are there any ways to fix this while slash command, embed, and ephemeral still remain?

Comment: @puncher I overrode your edit in order to add the library tag immediately. I'm not familiar with this library myself so I can't assess whether your change is correct. You could re-submit it, but actually I'd recommend suggesting it as a comment instead, since other edit reviewers also might not be able to assess it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters are wrong. The *first* parameter must be of type `discord.Interaction`. Also, you need to use type annotation on *all* parameters, because the API needs to know what the user is allowed/needs to type in as an argument.

Change the function definition to this:

```py
async def clear(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, num: int):
```

The 2nd error is caused by `ctx.respond`. `Interaction` doesn't have a method called `respond`, neither does `Context`, but it has an attribute `response` which returns an `InteractionResponse` object. And this object has a method called `send_message`.

So, the end result would look like that:

```py
@app_commands.command(name='clearmsg', description="clear the number of messages you want.")
@app_commands.rename(num='quantity')
@app_commands.describe(num='For how many messages you would like to delete (In Arabic numerals).')
async def clear(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, num: int):
  await interaction.channel.purge(limit=num)
  await interaction.response.send_message(f"{num} messages were cleared successfully.", embed=EmbedTemplate, ephemeral=True)
```

Here are a few more examples: https://gist.github.com/AbstractUmbra/a9c188797ae194e592efe05fa129c57f

---

###### References:

- [`discord.Interaction`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html?highlight=discord%20interaction#discord.Interaction)
- [`discord.InteractionResponse`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html?highlight=discord%20interaction#discord.InteractionResponse)
- [`InteractionResponse.send_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html?highlight=discord%20interaction#discord.InteractionResponse.send_message)

Comment: It actually works! I've been through lots of articles and documentations but none of them really point out the errors I got.
and none of them ever mentioned about `interaction.channel.purge`, so I used ctx instead.
Thanks for the solution! It saved me a lot of times!