# Hybrid Command gets error 'unsupported type annotation'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So I am rewriting a old bot I made and tested the clear command just to know if everything was right. But now I am getting an error:
`unsupported type annotation <class 'discord.ext.commands.context.Context'>`

The same happened when I changed everything to `interaction.send_message` and stuff.

However the error does not occur when it is a normal command (It just does nothing).
All I could find was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73363008/discord-py-typeerror-unsupported-type-annotation-class-discord-interactions-i) question which has the same eroor but with another class.
They suggested to put `self` before `interaction: discord.Interaction`, as well as changing everything to Interactions, which I also tried, but with the same error.

> Code

```
@bot.hybrid_command(name="clear")
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clear(self, ctx: commands.Context, amount=int):
    if amount > 20:
        await ctx.send("Because of Discords rate limit, I can\'t delete more than 50 messages at once.")
    elif amount <= 0:
        return ctx.send("I can't delete 0 messages")

    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount+1)
    return await ctx.send(f"Successfully deleted {amount} messages!")
```

Comment: If your function is being defined in a class (like `Cog`), then you don't need the `self` argument there. `discord.py` is thinking that the first argument of the command (`self`, in your case) is supposed to be a `context` and any other arguments after it will be the command's argument, so it thinks that you want the `ctx` argument to be a command argument, but the `commands.Context` annotation is not supported! Try removing the `self` argument and see what happens.

Comment: I did that, nothing changed, I also tried just putting ```ctx``` instead of ```ctx:  commands.Context```, it didn't change anything either

Comment: I think the correct way is to use `@commands.hybrid_command(name="clear")` to define your hybrid command in a Cog.

Comment: I am not using cogs, so this does not work either

Comment: @atomfrog, I've posted an answer that should help fix your normal version of the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why complicate a simple command? Why add `self`? You had another error in your code (you typed `=` instead of `:` to specify the type of `amount`). So, here's the code that I tried (I didn't get any errors, and it worked fine):

```py
@bot.hybrid_command(name="clear")
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clear(ctx, amount: int):
    if amount > 20:
        await ctx.send("Because of Discords rate limit, I can\'t delete more than 50 messages at once.")
    elif amount <= 0:
        return ctx.send("I can't delete 0 messages")

    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount+1)
    return await ctx.send(f"Successfully deleted {amount} messages!")
```

Note that a [`HybridCommand`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#hybridcommand) [has the same parameters and attributes as a regular](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#hybridcommand:%7E:text=has%20the%20same%20parameters%20and%20attributes%20as%20a%20regular%20Command) [`Command`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Command). So, the first parameter is the [`Context`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context). You can add the following two lines at the beginning of your `clear()` function's definition to check what I'm saying:

```py
print(type(ctx))
print(type(amount))
```

The output would be this:

```
<class 'discord.ext.commands.context.Context'>
<class 'int'>
```

Please note that this is for a normal command, not for `Interaction`s, but almost the same should work; you probably would have to add a parameter and handle it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, it works now, even though it only works when using a prefixed command instead of slash commands, which I believe is because of Discords time limit for interactions, which is 3 seconds. I still haven't figured a way to extend the time limit, but for now, it works.